# Unsure what is wrong with cron tab

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks, cron

I am attempting to schedule a cron job for database backups using percona extra backup.

My cron job is in cron.d and looks as follows;

```
exec &>/var/tmp/cron.log
1 * * * * * secondstory_prod /var/opt/backup/percona_xtrabackup_incremental.sh > /var/tmp/cron.log
```

The error i receive when i try and force the jobs to run in the log file listed above is `/etc/cron.d/db_backup_daily: line 2: 1: command not found`

If i try to run the jobs forcefully with `run-parts /etc/cron.d` i get the above error.

What is strange is that if i navigate to the directory and run the `percona_xtrabackup_incremental.sh` file it works with no issues.

Please can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: secondstory_prod is the owner?\

Comment: Is the script executable, with a ["shebang"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)?

Comment: yes
`-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  124 Aug 19 13:18 db_backup_daily*`

Comment: This `1` command not found sounds like your program is not interpreting it as a crontask.

Comment: what file type should it be in cron.d - a .sh file or any regular file? i created it using touch>filename with no extension

Comment: From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Advanced_Crontab I think you need the file to be named like an existing UNIX user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you have one too many `*` in your cron entry.

```
1 * * * * * secondstory_prod ..stuff..
```

should be

```
1 * * * * secondstory_prod ..stuff..
```

will run on every `1st` minute of each hour every day (above). The general time entry format is:

```
* minute (0-59)
* hour (0-23)
* day of month (1-31)
* month (1-12)
* day of week (0-6) (0=Sunday)
```